# FindIndex on list by linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

How may i get index using linq ? I want to find by FieldNo and get back to index. let say if i search 2 it should be return index 1.

[image]

Regards,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With LINQ:

```
int index = fields.Select((f, i) => new { Field = f, Index = i})
    .Where(x => x.Field.FieldNo == 2)
    .Select(x => x.Index)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(-1)
    .First();
```

without LINQ using [`List.FindIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), more readable, efficient and works even on [.NET 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
int index = fields.FindIndex(f => f.FieldNo == 2);
```

---

The above code used anonymous-types which are GC heap-allocated, which may cause performance issues - so if you're using .NET Core or .NET Framework 4.7 or later we should use `ValueTuple` instead which avoids using the heap at all for maximum performance:

```
int index = fields
    .Select((f, idx) => (f, idx))
    .Where(t => t.f.FieldNo == 2)
    .Select(t => t.idx)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(-1)
    .First();
```

Or slightly more succinctly by using `FirstOrDefault` and the Elvis operator:

```
int index = fields
    .Select((f, idx) => (f, idx))
    .FirstOrDefault(t => t.f.FieldNo == 2)
    ?.idx ?? -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question right, this is what you need:

```
Field field = Field.Where(x => x.FieldNo == 2).FirstOrDefault();
if (field != null)
    {
        Field.IndexOf(field);
    }
```

Comment: This is quite inefficient; it has to traverse the list twice and unnecessarily compare each item in the second run against the value that was already reached in the first run.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use this `overload` of `.Select`,

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, TResult> selector);
```

like this:

```
List.Select((t, index) => t );
```

but i think this will be worked if your collection is in memory, else it will be caused an exception